# Encontrar la persona con menor edad

Tags: c++

Tengo dos arrays en *C++*, uno con los nombres de personas y otro con las edades.

¿Cómo podría encontrar la persona con menor edad y mostrarla en pantalla?

Ejemplo:

> Alejandro 37 
>   Tatiana   28 
>   María     52

... y que muestre en pantalla, *La persona con menor edad es Tatiana.*

Tengo este código:

```
int n;
char nombre[8][20];
int edad[8];
int numero[100];
int menor=100;

cout<<"Digite la cantidad de jugadores: ";
cin>>n;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){    
    cout<<"\nDigite el nombre del jugador "<<i+1<<" : ";
    cin>>nombre[i];
    cout<<"Digite la edad del jugador "<<i+1<<" : ";
    cin>>edad[i];
}
cout<<"\n";

for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    cout<<"Jugador "<<i+1<<" -> "<<nombre[i]<<endl;
}
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    if(edad[i] < menor){
        menor = edad[i];
        cout<<"\nEl menor elemento del vector es: "<<nombre[i]<<" "<<menor<<endl;
    }
}
```

... y me imprime esta pantalla:

> Digite la cantidad de jugadores: 4
>
> Digite el nombre del jugador 1: María 
>   Digite la edad del jugador 1: 52
>
> Digite el nombre del jugador 2: Juan 
>   Digite la edad del jugador 2: 20
>
> Digite el nombre del jugador 3: Pablo 
>   Digite la edad del jugador 3: 14
>
> Digite el nombre del jugador 4: Carmen 
>   Digite la edad del jugador 4: 32
>
> Jugador 1 -> María 
>   Jugador 2 -> Juan 
>   Jugador 3 -> Pablo 
>   Jugador 4 -> Carmen
>
> El menor elemento del vector es: María 52 
>   El menor elemento del vector es: Juan 20 
>   El menor elemento del vector es: Pablo 14

Necesito que me imprima en este caso: *El menor elemento del vector es: Pablo 14*

Esto debido a que Pablo es el de menor edad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias hacerlo definiendo una clase `Persona` que tenga los atributos `nombre` y `edad` (de esta forma al crear un objeto de este tipo tendras asociado un `nombre` y `edad` a una `Persona`), estos objetos podrian tener estos atributos como publicos o como privados y ser accedidos mediante metodos (cuando se programa orientado a objetos la idea es hacerlo de esta ultima forma).

Entonces finalmente puedes crear un arreglo de varios objetos de tipo `Persona` y buscar por el objeto de este tipo que tenga la menor edad recorriendo el arreglo entero con un simple `for` y comparando las edades con el metodo anteriormente mencionado.

Entonces los pasos serian:

1. Recorrer arreglos de nombres y edades e instanciar los objetos de tipo `Persona`.
2. Encontrar el objeto de tipo `Persona` que tenga la menor edad e imprimir su nombre.

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo para que te guies, solamente te faltaria crear el arreglo de `Personas` a partir de tus arreglos de nombres y edades.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Persona {
  public:
    Persona(std::string nombre, int edad);
    std::string getNombre();
    int getEdad();

  private:
    std::string nombre;
    int edad;
};

Persona::Persona(std::string nombre, int edad) {
  this->nombre = nombre;
  this->edad = edad;
}

std::string Persona::getNombre() {
  return nombre;
}

int Persona::getEdad() {
  return edad;
}

int main( ) {
  Persona P1("Juan", 35);
  Persona P2("Maria", 20);
  Persona P3("Roberto", 49);
  Persona P4("Patricio", 19);
  Persona P5("Fernanda", 25);

  Persona arreglo[5] = {P1, P2, P3, P4, P5};

  int menorEdad = arreglo[0].getEdad();

  Persona resultado(arreglo[0]);

  for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    if (menorEdad > arreglo[i].getEdad()) {
      resultado = arreglo[i];
      menorEdad = arreglo[i].getEdad();
    }

  std::cout << "Las persona con menor edad es " << resultado.getNombre();

  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**:

Considerando el codigo que pusiste el error lo tienes en esta parte.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (edad[i] < menor) {
    menor = edad[i];
    cout << "\nEl menor elemento del vector es: " << nombre[i] << " " << menor << endl;
  }
}
```

Ya que `menor` lo defines como un entero igual a 100, y dentro del bucle `for` (que recorre el arreglo entero) cada vez que encuentre alguien con una edad menor a `menor` la ejecucion entrara al `if` y se imprimira por pantalla `El menor elemento del vector es...` y se actualizara el valor de `menor`, pero lo que tu quieres hacer es imprimir solamente el menor de todos, por lo que deberias cambiar eso por este otro codigo:

```
int indice_menor = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (edad[i] < menor) {
    menor = edad[i];
    indice_menor = i;
  }
}

cout << "\nEl menor elemento del vector es: " << nombre[indice_menor] << " " << menor << endl;
```

Aqui lo que se haria es encontrar el indice que corresponde a la menor edad de todos y despues se imprime el mensaje una sola vez con los datos del que tiene la menor edad.

Saludos!

Comment: Te agradezco la ayuda, pero me quede perdido jejeje, recien estoy aprendiendo C++ y es una tarea, ademas me editaron la pregunta, ya que los datos no los posea yo (nombre y edad) estos datos los pide el programa y el usuario los debe digitar asi como la cantidad de personas.

Comment: @Ali-Rash Para ingresar los datos mientras este tu programa esta ejecutandose podrias usar `cin`, aqui te dejo un [enlace](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/) para que veas lo basico de input/output en C++.

Si tienes mas dudas no dudes en preguntar, pero primero investiga por tu cuenta tambien, asi llegas con dudas mas especificas y no tan generales.

Comment: @Ali-Rash Acao de editar mi respuesta considerando el codigo que pusiste hace poco.

Comment: @CodigoFacil que lo agradezco amigo eso era exactamente lo que buscaba, no comprendía mi gran error y con el codigo que me corregiste comprendí perfectamente, ahora lo adaptare al resto de mi codigo, muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada, a todos nos pasan esos tipos de errores de vez en cuando, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Propongo una variante que usa la función min_element de la biblioteca estándar C++ y una expresión lambda como predicado, como una forma C++11 de abordar el problema.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

// datos de un jugador
struct Jugador {
    std::string nombre;
    int edad;
};
// [NOTA] Como los miembros nombre y edad van a ser accedidos directamente,
// tanto para lectura como para escritura, no necesitan ser privados
// o funciones de acceso.

int main()
{
    // cantidad de jugadores:
    int n;
    std::cout << "Digite la cantidad de jugadores: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    // vector de Personas:
    std::vector<Jugador> grupo;

    // variables auxiliares para facilitar la entrada de datos
    std::string nombre;
    int edad;

    // creas cada Jugador y lo incluyes en el grupo:
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cout << "nombre del jugador: ";
        std::cin >> nombre;
        std::cout << "edad del jugador: ";
        std::cin >> edad;

        grupo.push_back({ nombre, edad }); // ingreas este jugador al gurpo
    }

    // obtienes el jugador de menor edad 
    // con la función de la biblioteca estándar min_element
    // usando como predicado una expresión que devuelve el menor de dos ints
    auto it = std::min_element(grupo.begin(), grupo.end(),
        [](const Jugador& j1, const Jugador& j2)
    { return j1.edad < j2.edad; });

    std::cout << "el jugador de menor edad es: " << it->nombre << ' ' << ' '  
              << it->edad << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Pues mostrar la edad de menor a mayor o viceversa es fácil, basta con hacer el algoritmo de la burbuja para que te lo ordene y listo, pero tienes que relacionar el arreglo de edad con el de los nombres, tiene que haber algún tipo de relación, ya sea por el índice o por su posición

Comment: Exacto amigo eso es lo que no se como hacer, como relacionar los dos arreglos

Comment: Considera la posibilidad de añadir el código que explique la solución que propones